# Redraw Datatables after action

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

Im having problems getting my datatable to refresh. I have a button which calls an update script and a confirmation message before it does anything. This all works fine but, I would like the table to refresh to get the new results. Here is what I have so far.

```
function unapprove_link(data)
{
    var str = $(this).attr('title');
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to UNAPPROVE this lead?");
    if (!answer) return false;
    $.post("actions/unapprove-lead.php",
    {'lead_id': data},
        function()
        {
            oTable.fnClearTable(0);
            oTable.fnDraw();
        }
);

}
```

Here is my full code:

```
            $(document).ready(function()
              {
        /*      // Unapprove Lead Alert
                $('.unapprove').live('click', function() {
                var str = $(this).attr('title');
                var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to UNAPPROVE this lead?");
                oTable.fnDraw();
                if (!answer) return false;
                });
                // Delete Lead Alert
                $('.delete').live('click', function() {
                var str = $(this).attr('title');
                var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to DELETE this lead?");
                oTable.fnDraw();
                if (!answer) return false;
                });
        */
                var anOpen = [];
                var oTable = $('#example').dataTable
                ({
                      'bProcessing': true,
                      'aaSorting': [[1,'asc']], // sorts date by default.
                      'iDisplayLength': 10,
                      'bJQueryUI': true,
                      'bStateSave': true,
                      'bServerSide': true,
                      'sAjaxSource': 'ajax/pc-ajax-table.php',
                      'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
                  {

                      aoData.push( { "name": "from_date", "value": $( "#from" ).val() },
                                   { "name": "to_date", "value": $( "#to" ).val() } );
                    $.ajax
                        ({
                          'dataType': 'json',
                          'type'    : 'POST',
                          'url'     : sSource,
                          'data'    : aoData,
                          'success' : fnCallback
                        });
                  },
                       'aoColumns':[
                      {"bVisible": false, "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": true}, 
                      {"fnRender": format_ddmmyyyy}, // renders the date as dd/mm/yyyy
                      null,  // name
                      null,  // lead location
                      null, // course type
                      {"bVisible": false, "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": true},
                      {"bVisible": false, "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": true},
                      {"bVisible": false, "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": true},
                      {"bVisible": false, "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": true},
                      null,
                      null,
                      {"sClass": "control", "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false},
                      {"bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false},
                      {"bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false}]
                });
                // for adding a details box
            $('#example td.control').live( 'click', function () {
              var nTr = this.parentNode;
              var i = $.inArray( nTr, anOpen );

              if ( i === -1 ) {
                $('img', this).attr( 'src', "../images/details_close.png" );
                var nDetailsRow = oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
                $('div.innerDetails', nDetailsRow).slideDown();
                anOpen.push( nTr );
              }
              else {
                $('img', this).attr( 'src', "../images/details_open.png" );
                $('div.innerDetails', $(nTr).next()[0]).slideUp( function () {
                  oTable.fnClose( nTr );
                  anOpen.splice( i, 1 );
                } );
              }
            } );

            function fnFormatDetails( oTable, nTr )
            {
              var oData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
              var sOut =
                '<div class="innerDetails">'+   
                '<div style="padding:6px; background-color:#FFF;">Enquiry: <span style="color:#2663A4;">'+oData[8]+'</span></div>'+
                '<div style="padding:6px; background-color:#FFF;">Email: <span style="color:#2663A4;">'+oData[5]+'</span></div>'+
                '<div style="padding:6px; background-color:#FFF;">Phone: <span style="color:#2663A4;">'+oData[6]+'</span></div>'+
                '<div style="padding:6px; background-color:#FFF;">IP Address: <span style="color:#2663A4;">'+oData[7]+'</span></div>'+
                '<div style="padding:6px; background-color:#FFF;">Lead ID: <span style="color:#2663A4;">'+oData[0]+'</span></div>'+
                '<div style="height:6px;"></div>'+      
                '<div class="light-blue-underline-main" style="margin:0px;"></div>'+
                '<div style="height:6px;"></div>'+      
                '</div>';
              return sOut;
            }
            // For clicking and selecting the date ranges
            $("button").button().click(function() {
                oTable.fnDraw();
              });
            var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
              defaultDate: "+1w",
              changeMonth: true,
              changeYear: true,
              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
              onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                  instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                  date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
              }
            });
        });
        // Take date from mysql, formatted yyyy-mm-dd, and return as dd/mm/yyyy
        function format_ddmmyyyy(oObj) {
          var sValue = oObj.aData[oObj.iDataColumn]; 
          var aDate = sValue.split('-');
          return aDate[2] + "/" + aDate[1] + "/" + aDate[0];
        }

        // Highlight Rows
        $("tbody tr").live("mouseover", function(){
            $(this).children().addClass("highlighted");
        });
        $("tbody tr").live("mouseout", function(){
            $(this).children().removeClass("highlighted");
        });
        // Actions for Unapprove button
        function unapprove_link(data)
            {
                var str = $(this).attr('title');
                var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to UNAPPROVE this lead?");
                if (!answer) return false;
                $.post("actions/unapprove-lead.php",
                {"lead_id": data},
                    function(data)
                    {
                     oTable.fnDraw();
                    }
            );

        }
        /*// Actions for Delete button
        function delete_link(data)
            {
                $.post("actions/delete-lead.php",
                {'lead_id': data},
                    function(data)
                    {
                    oTable.fnDraw();
                    }
            );

        }
        */
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling *oTable.fnDraw()* will cause the refresh for sure. You are doing *$.post*, I would change it to *.$ajax*, also, you don't seem to be doing anything with the data returned from the post operation. Remember, DataTable expects an oData object somewhere in the response if you expect it to rebind the data.

In fact, datatable expects a lot more, you need to return the number of items in total, the number being displayed on the page, etc.

Comment: if you have the time could you tell me where I need to change my current code. Have added full code above.

Comment: Will gladly do so, but will have to be tomorrow since I am at a pub, typing from my cell; however, I can tell you right now that the function on the server side that will be called when you do *fnDraw* is going to be *ajax/pc-ajax-table.php* because that's what you defined on your markup. You can clear the table and add rows programmatically, which seems to be your intention, but you need to iterate through your result set and call fnAddRow or something like that. Check the documentation, I am sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: thanks mate, think i will have to go do some more research or settle for a page refresh. In the pub? are you from the UK if so, it's a little early in on a sunday morning for drinking isn't it? :)

Comment: @monsterboy I am in the US and I am on vacations so it's cool. Good luck! :)